# Symfony2.2 and SonataProject

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

I am a newbie in Symfony2 and Php and I want to install Sonata project.
In all tutorial I've found I do understand that I need to update the `Composer.json`, the kernel, the config ,etc.
When once they talk about running a command like for example: "php composer.phar update" I have no idea where to do that I have no idea where this command is and where I should write that!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install php to your server or machine. Because it is required to use php console line interface. After installation you have to install composer.phar from http://getcomposer.org/ then you can call that command which you mention. There is also some useful information about composer on that site which I refer.

Comment: I did all of this. I have php on my machine and I just installed the composer .. from where can I call this command?

Comment: You have to call it where composer.json located. It always locates in project directory

Comment: I think you don't get me :) 

Let me try to be clearer. 
In the tutorials, they ask me to update composer.json, the app Kernel, the config file .. Once I do all of these they ask me to run a command from something that look like a command line HOW can I open this command line? (the black little board -- (nooot windowns command line))

Comment: Start -> Run then write cmd. After open command line you have to follow this instruction http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Comment: If you use linux you have to open terminal app then you have to follow this instruction http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-nix